# Eloquent Accessor: update attribute on model instance

Tags: json, laravel, encryption, eloquent, accessor

I want to decrypt the email attribute of my model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'password',
    'remember_token',
    'status',
    'name',
    'lastname',
    'password_changed_at',
    'role',
    'attempts'
];
```

By using this mutator with JSON Append

```
protected $appends = ['email'];

public function getEmailAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['email'] === Crypt::decrypt($value);
}
```

The problem I'm facing it's that when I execute  a dump and die, the response hasn't change the email attribute.

[image: Dump and Die Response]

Any ideas on how i can change the response to return the email decrypted?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `appends`, try below:

```
public function getEmailAttribute($value)
{
    return Crypt::decrypt($value);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this method only triggers the decrypted value, if you access it directly, for example $user->email. But if you call the whole instance of the model, the attribute stays the same.

Comment: What you mean about `call the whole instance of the model`? Could you show your code?

Comment: If you want to use `append`,
```
protected $appends = ['decrypted_email'];

public function getDecryptedEmailAttribute()
{
    return Crypt::decrypt($this->email);
}
```

Comment: For example, I'm encrypting the email field for the login, the controller its obviously not working because its looking for the plaintext of the email, and retrieving the user, reveals that the decryption kicks in only after it is in blade or you call it directly like $this->email